# Как изменить логику восстановления пароля в Laravel Auth?

Tags: php, laravel, авторизация, пароль, восстановление

Добрый день! Вопрос такой, есть проект написанный на Laravel какой то рандомной командой кодеров, и так вышло что мне его нужно доделать, и одна из проблем это неработающая система восстановления пароля, которая, как я понимаю является модифицированной версией обычной Auth в Laravel (почему модифицированной, потому что при восстановлении пароля вместо дефолтных двух паролей в laravel там просит еще и почту ввести, и валидирует по ней), в конечном счете выходило так что выдавало ошибку именно на поле с почтой, дословно - Неверный токен. Понятно что написано там было все мягко говоря через одно место, поэтому такая магия там и происходила, но когда я убрал это поле, при введении двух паролей страница просто обновляется и все, ничего не происходит, лазил по контроллеру, однако для меня как для относительного новичка в ларке там особо ничего понятно не было.

Вопрос. Где найти валидации и вообще код который относится именно к странице /password/reset и т.д. , так как в контроллере ничего нету связанного с валидацией этих паролей, и алгоритма в целом?
Или даже скорее всего, как переустановить модуль Auth ?

Заранее спасибо, мой первый вопрос, если что сразу прошу прощения за кол-во текста, пытался максимально детально описать суть )

Ранее подсказали что проблема может быть в форме, но скорее всего нет, вот код формы:

```html
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST"
                                      action="{{ route('password.request',[],false) }}">
                                    {{ csrf_field() }}

                                    <input type="hidden" name="token" value="{{ $token }}">

                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="password" class="col-md-4 control-label"
                                               style="color:#fff;">Password</label>

                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="password">
                                                <input type="password" name="password" id="password" value="" required>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"
                                                      data-target="password"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            @if ($errors->has('password'))
                                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('password_confirmation') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                                        <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 control-label"
                                               style="color:#fff;">Confirm Password</label>
                                        <div class="col-md-6">
                                            <div class="password">
                                                <input type="password" name="password_confirmation"
                                                       id="password-confirm" value=""
                                                       required>
                                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"
                                                      data-target="password-confirm"></span>
                                            </div>

                                            @if ($errors->has('password_confirmation'))
                                                <span class="help-block">
                                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('password_confirmation') }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <div class="btn">
                                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" style="cursor:pointer;">
                                                Reset Password
                                            </button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </form>
```

Comment: Мы ничего не сможем сказать исходя из кода формы. Возможно она и верна, а может и нет О_о. А вообще они могли менять код по такому пути: `project name\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\и тут то, что Вам нужно`

Comment: @D3V1L а какая версия Laravel? Как удалить - можно посмотреть по ссылке: [how-to-remove-auth-in-laravel-php-artisan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41855619/how-to-remove-auth-in-laravel-php-artisan)

Comment: @Эдуард, Laravel 5.4.27, но я думаю что это не поможет, так как по тому гайду удаляется только вьюшки, а сами контроллеры, которые скорее всего изменялись, и я не знаю где именно, останутся прежними, и ничего не изменится.

Comment: @D3V1L а в исходный код класса `MakeAuthCommand`, как я понял, вы не посмотрели? По ссылке из предыдущего камента об этом сразу же упоминается, а уже потом - об удалении вьюшек. Я напишу вам где контроллеры, но лучше будет, если вы сами сможете их отыскать, т.к. нужно же уметь ориентироваться в коде фв.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*(этот ответ - дополнение к комментарию)*

**Стандартные файлы авторизации/регистрации Laravel 5.4**

---

Миграции:

```
проект/database/migrations/2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table.php
проект/database/migrations/2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table.php
```

Модель User:

```
проект/app/User.php
```

Контроллеры:

```
проект/app/Http/Controllers/HomeController.php
проект/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ForgotPasswordController.php
проект/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php
проект/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php
проект/app/Http/Controllers/Auth/ResetPasswordController.php
```

Шаблоны:

```
проект/resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php
проект/resources/views/home.blade.php
проект/resources/views/auth/passwords/email.blade.php
проект/resources/views/auth/passwords/reset.blade.php
проект/resources/views/auth/login.blade.php
проект/resources/views/auth/register.blade.php
```

Маршруты в файле `проект/routes/web.php`:

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');
```

Comment: спасибо, я гуглил, думал может командой можно какой то убрать, но старым добрым способом - руками тоже можно )